# How to find out how many websites uses multi-page design or single-page design?

Tags: web-crawler, analytics, single-page-application, alexa-skills-kit

For my paper, I'm doing comparisons between Multi-page and Single-page design. I want to compare the statistics of how many websites use them

Is there a way to find this information? or do I have to crawl to find websites from something like Alexa top 1 Million sites? Even with the crawling method, how would you determine an MPA/SPA?

Is there a better way of finding this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [CommonCrawl](http://commoncrawl.org/) instead of crawling, its coverage is pretty large and it is perfect for that sort of studies. See also this [article](https://dzone.com/articles/need-billions-of-web-pages-dont-bother-crawling) I wrote not long ago.

Comment: From the example section on CommonCrawl (http://commoncrawl.org/the-data/examples/), this seems to be on the right path, cheers!